# how to apply fourier analyis to a vector of 736 temp readings (one every 3 hours for 3 months)

Tags: matlab, fft, temperature

I have a vector of 736 temperature readings, one for every 3rd hour between jun-aug, therefore 8 per day for jun-aug.

I need to apply a Fourier analysis to this vector. I have normalized it. I have searched all over (because I really don't understand matlab) and all I see are these analysis with signs where you already have a sampling to compare it to (like 1000Hz keeps coming up). the sampling interval is 3hrs and the length of sampling is 90 days. I don't know how to do this. any help would REALLY help.

thank you, I am desperate.

Answer (score 4):

The FFT operation is actually agnostic of the input sampling rate.  The sampling rate is only used after the FFT is performed to interpret the frequencies of the output.

So, basically you can take the FFT of your vector and it will transform your 736 samples at discrete time instants into 736 samples at discrete frequencies.  These frequencies are given by

```
F(k) = Fs * k / Nfft
```

Where Fs is the sampling rate and Nfft is the number of FFT points.  The output vector from the FFT will be complex. In most cases, you will want to take the magnitude of the output to produce values proportional to the amount of energy at each frequency.

The MATLAB code may look like this:

```
x = %your input vector
Nfft = length(x);
Fs = 1 / (60 * 60 * 3);  %1 / 3hrs
Xk = fft(x);
k = 0 : Nfft-1;
Fk = Fs * k / Nfft;  %frequency vector

%plot frequency versus magnitude in dB scale
Plot(Fk, 20 * log10(abs(Xk)));
```

There are several other issues you need to be aware of:

- Assuming your input is real-valued, the second half of the FFT output vector will be a mirror image of the first half. In this case, only the first half of the output is needed, giving you frequencies from 0 to Fs/2
- Fs/2, the Nyquist rate, is the maximum frequency that can be represented by a signal sampled at Fs.  So, for example, if there are temperature fluctuations within the 3 hours between samples, this information is not accurately captured by a 3hr sampling period.

I've left out a lot of details, but I tried to just give you enough info to get a frequency-magnitude plot without complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation. I would add that `fftshift` might be handy to plot the zero-frequency component at center, instead of at right

Comment: Correct answer, but – I'm always wary of people without experience asking about the Fourier transform. Doesn't the poster actually want to do spectral estimation? For which one needs to take care of boundary effects, use averaging across shorter windows to get a decent estimate, etc. etc.